# I don't seem to have pip even when I downloaded the newer versions of python

Tags: python, pip

I have downloaded python version 3.7 and have checked my command prompt but it seems that I still do not have pip installed. I thought it came with the newer versions of python. If im just being dumb let me know im new to this. Thanks so much.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: What OS? How did you install Python?

Answer (score -1):

I think you have not installed pip here. To do so, here is the way.

Donwload the pypi file from here :https://pypi.org/project/pip/
After downloading, open cmd and move to the folder. then type:

```
python pypi.py #change pypi with the file name
```